# Is there a way to store archived logback's .gz log files in a separate folder?

Tags: java, logback, gzip

I want to store current log file in `/logs` folder, and all old archived `.gz` files in `/logs/archive`. Is there is a way to configure logback for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can add `rolling policy` to the `appender` :

```
<appender name="MAIN" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/your-app-logs.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_GZ_DIR}/your-app-logs.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- keep 90 days' worth of history capped at 3GB total size -->
        <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

Comment: ok. this config will archive log files, but will not move them into another folder, as i want, or i don't understand something?

Comment: Note `${LOG_DIR}` for `.log` files and `${LOG_GZ_DIR}` for `.log.gz` files. You can replace `${LOG_DIR}` with `/logs` and `${LOG_GZ_DIR}` with `/logs/archive`, or set them as properties in `logback.xml`, that should to the trick

Comment: txn for expaining, now i understand